# remove special charecters in a string using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a `string = "msdjdgf(^&%*(Aroha Technologies&^$^&*^CHJdjg"` with special characters.

what i am trying is to remove all special charecters in the string and then display the word 'Aroha Technologies'

i was able to do with hard coding using `lstrip()` function but can anyone help me out how can i display string 'Aroha Technologies' in a single line using regular expressions.

edit suggested:-

by using this `lstrip()` and `rstrip()` functions i was able to remove characters from the string.

```
str = "msdjdgf(^&%*(Aroha Technologies&^$^&*^CHJdjg"

str=str.lstrip('msdjdgf(^&%*(')

str=str.rstrip('&^$^&*^CHJdjg')
```

Comment: here msdjdgf are not special characters. So you cannot do this using lstrip()

Comment: @gaur93 by using this hard coded function i was able to remove unwanted charecters str.lstrip('msdjdgf(^&%*(')

Comment: @sunilBhatraju Please show the proper code you tried to get output

Comment: `S = "msdjdgf(^&%(Aroha Technologies&^$^&^CHJdjg"`; `res = 'Aroha Technologies'`; `S[S.find(res):S.find(res) + len(res)]`.

Comment: @sunilBhatraju If you know characters between  which your substring will lie you can find your substring by slicing operator

Comment: How are you logically defining what you want to _keep_  and how are you differentiating this from what you don't want to keep?

Comment: I know a way to strip off special characters, but that still leaves you with alphanum gibberish.  How do you intend to isolate what you want?

Comment: For that matter, what have *you* tried using regex?

Comment: @srig is this the correct way of removing all special characters and junk characters from above string with out using any hard coding

Comment: @sunilBhatraju, that's how I would do it without regex.

Comment: Careful using `strip` and its variants to remove characters, because it may remove more than you expect: `"HIJK!@#$Hello".lstrip("HIJK!@#$")` gives `'ello'`. If you just want to slice the first N characters off the front of a string, use slicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here, A bit more *dirty* approach

```
import re # A module in python for String matching/operations  
a = "msdjdgf(^&%*(Aroha Technologies&^$^&*^CHJdjg"
stuff = re.findall('\W(\w+\s\w+)\W', a)
print(stuff[0]) # Aroha Technologies
```

hope this helps ;)

Comment: its working but can u explain what this line(stuff = re.findall('\W(\w+\s\w+)\W', a)) does?

Comment: `findall` finds all the occurrences of `Aroha Technologies` in the string but the constraint is that it must be surrounded by ***non word characters (\W) separated by a white-space (\s)***, and `a` is the string, finally we save all the juice in stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide a lot of information, so this may or may not be close to what you want:

```
import re
origstr = "msdjdgf(^&%(Aroha Technologies&^$^&^CHJdjg"
match = re.search("[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*", origstr)
if match:
    newstr = match.group()
```

(looks for a series of capitalized words with spaces between them)

Comment: what is re? can elaborate the answer u provided it will be helpful

Comment: @sunilBhatraju, you are asking for an answer using regular expressions. [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is a module in Python used for regular expression operations.

Comment: kk thanks @srig i just checked it but i was unable to display the string after trying the answer u provided

Comment: Using `str` as a variable name overrides the built-in type.

Comment: @sunilBhatraju, do you mean my answer in the comments?

Comment: Also, a semicolon is not needed to terminate a statement. I know that must be a typo :)